# Method in child class not updating JTextField

Tags: java

```
public class Calculator extends JComponent {

    Result rez = new Result();

    public void init() {

        Frame frame = new Frame();
        Panel panel = new Panel();

        panel.add(rez);
        frame.add(panel);

        Test test = new Test(); <- I thing this is the problem, instancing a child inside a parent. Not sure.
        test.test(); <- doing nothing

    }
}
class Frame extends JFrame {
    public Frame() {
        // .. setVisible, setTitle....
    }
}
class Panel extends JPanel {
    public Panel() {
        // setBounds, setLayout

    }
}
class Test extends Calculator {
    public void test() {
        rez.setText("Test"); <- This does nothing
    }
}
```

Trying to make a calculator and I'm having trouble updating the results box. The method `test()` in the `Test` class is not updating the JTextBox.

However, if i create a method in the main `Calculator()` class, called `update()` and put the `rez.setText()` inside, it works every time.

This works tho:

```
public class Calculator extends JComponent {

    Result rez = new Result();

    public void init() {

        Frame frame = new Frame();
        Panel panel = new Panel();

        panel.add(rez);
        frame.add(panel);

        this.update(); <- works

    }
    public void update() {
            rez.setText("Test"); <- works
        }
    }
```

Why is that? Extended classes should share variables. Should they?

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to update the code with a class?

Comment: It will be a  Math class, that does the actual computing. I want to handle the result printing and updating.

Comment: Try `public Result = new Result();` instead of `Result = new Result();`

Comment: @Dan If visibility were the issue he should get a compiler error.  If not, then making `rez` public should not matter.

Comment: @Gala You are not providing enough codes to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't think it should work because you are creating frame and panel local to your super class init method. In the same method you are instantiating `testclass` which eventually call constructor of the super class. But for this `testclass`, frame and panel are no where in picture ? How would you even see the change itself ?